# Calculated field value in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I need to translate the following query which is executed in SQL Server to Oracle.

```
SELECT 
    LABEL_A, LABEL_B, 
    CASE
        WHEN IS_C = '0' AND IS_B = 'S' THEN 'L1'
        WHEN IS_C = '1' AND IS_B = 'B' THEN 'L1'
        WHEN IS_C = '0' AND IS_B = 'B' THEN 'L2'
        WHEN IS_C = '1' AND IS_B = 'S' THEN 'L2'
    END AS L,
    QTY
FROM
    DATA
WHERE 
    PRICE > 0 AND E_DATE >= getdate()-1) AS LS
GROUP BY 
    LABEL_A, LABEL_B, L
HAVING 
    SUM(QTY/100) >= 150
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post what you tried so far and the issue you are having

Comment: Does that query really execute with SQL Server?

Comment: Other than the typos on the `WHERE` clause, I would replace `getdate()` with `sysdate` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main challenge in porting from SQL Server to Oracle is that the latter does not allow aliases in the `SELECT` statement to be used in the `GROUP BY` clause.  But instead of repeating the lengthy `CASE` expression, we can use a subquery to reuse it.

```
SELECT t.LABEL_A,
       t.LABEL_B,
       t.L,
       SUM(t.QTY) AS QTY
FROM
(
    SELECT LABEL_A,
           LABEL_B, 
           CASE WHEN IS_C = '0' AND IS_B = 'S' THEN 'L1'
                WHEN IS_C = '1' AND IS_B = 'B' THEN 'L1'
                WHEN IS_C = '0' AND IS_B = 'B' THEN 'L2'
                WHEN IS_C = '1' AND IS_B = 'S' THEN 'L2'
           END AS L,
           QTY
    FROM DATA
    WHERE PRICE > 0 AND E_DATE >= SYSDATE - 1
) t
GROUP BY t.LABEL_A, t.LABEL_B, t.L
HAVING SUM(t.QTY)/100 >= 150
```

Comment: This still has an unmatched `)` parenthesis in the inner `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This could also be done at a `CTE` with a preceding `WITH` statement. They usually make things a little more readable. At least IMO.

Comment: @gmiley, and I find this derived table a little more readable. Just a matter of taste.

Comment: It was just a suggestion for completeness. It's a perfectly fine answer, I just thought it could be further enhanced with a mention of CTEs. Not to mention that in some instances they can provide better performance than a subquery.

Comment: @gmiley I completely agree with you, though for someone reading this question a year from now, the subquery I have above might be easier to digest than a separate CTE.  But a CTE might benefit more in the sense of making the subquery easily reusable.  Speaking as a software person this makes using a CTE here more appealing than a small performance boost.

Comment: The re-usability of a CTE is what I was getting at for performance increase as a CTE is only executed once, whereas subqueries could be executed multiple times. Then you could see even more issues with further nested subqueries. As a note on my comment, I wasn't suggesting you change your answer. I just wanted to mention the CTE alternative at least in a comment related to it.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the errors are in this line:

```
WHERE PRICE > 0 AND E_DATE] >= getdate()-1) AS LS
```

You have extra `]` and `)` characters and `getdate()` is replaced by `SYSDATE` and you need to remove the alias at the end of the line. Apart from that, you can't use a column alias in the `GROUP BY` clause and need to use the entire case statement (or wrap it in a sub-query).

You also have the issue that `QTY` is not part of the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT LABEL_A,
       LABEL_B, 
       CASE
         WHEN IS_C = '0' AND IS_B = 'S' THEN 'L1'
         WHEN IS_C = '1' AND IS_B = 'B' THEN 'L1'
         WHEN IS_C = '0' AND IS_B = 'B' THEN 'L2'
         WHEN IS_C = '1' AND IS_B = 'S' THEN 'L2'
       END AS L,
       SUM( QTY ) AS QTY
FROM   DATA
WHERE  PRICE > 0
AND    E_DATE >= SYSDATE-1
GROUP BY
       LABEL_A,
       LABEL_B,
       CASE
         WHEN IS_C = '0' AND IS_B = 'S' THEN 'L1'
         WHEN IS_C = '1' AND IS_B = 'B' THEN 'L1'
         WHEN IS_C = '0' AND IS_B = 'B' THEN 'L2'
         WHEN IS_C = '1' AND IS_B = 'S' THEN 'L2'
       END
HAVING SUM(QTY/100) >= 150
```

Comment: Instead of repeating the case expression in the GROUP BY, I'd wrap the query up in a derived table.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

> ```
> WHERE PRICE > 0 AND E_DATE] >= getdate()-1) AS LS
> ```

remove here `]` and `)` (which seem to be invalid in MS too) and replace `getDate()` with `sysdate`. Rest should be ok except group by that needs to replace `L` with whole `CASE` statement.

Comment: Also the extra close paren `)` in the where clause.

Comment: @gmiley yes I'll add it

Comment: He mentions `sysdate` in the text, it just isn't in the top example.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it is quoted line from question

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes and this is answer. I've quoted what OP has and written what he need to change.